# How to delete a row from AP_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL Oracle R12 table?

Tags: oracle, api

[image]Please I need to know how to delete a row from AP_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL table in oracle R12?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to delete all rows? If you can't use HOLD_FLAG to 'Y' to place a hold on the scheduled payment ?
- Abhi

Comment: Thank you for your feeedback Abhi, actually I want to delete one row which is an extra line created without due date and gross amout as you can see in screen shot above. this row was created automatically and it has no sense. so I need to make a datafix to delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/farel9/financialscs_gs/OEDMF/AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL_tbl.htm) the primary key on AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL is `INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID`. Therefore, given a valid value for INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID you'd do something like

```
DELETE FROM AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL
  WHERE INVOICE_PAYMENT_ID = #####
```

where ##### is the invoice payment ID.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your feedback, I need an API which can delete from this table in order to do safe delete.